# Scrollmagic pin

Tags: javascript, scrollmagic

I have a bootstrap row, that contains a `table__tabs` and a `table__info`, and looks like this:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="table__tabs col-md-2">...</div>
    <div class="table__info col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">...</div>
</div>
```

What I wanted to do is to pin it while I scroll for the duration that equal `.table__info` height, which is dynamic.

How am I able to 'unpin' the div when the bottom of the screen touches the end of the `.table__info`?